# React-Bootstrap TypeScript - How to create a ImageButton

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, imagebutton

Long time I haven't come on SO to post a question but today... I am stuck on a new story and require your help!

I am trying to **reproduce a design *(html/css/jquery)*** (that is way to hard to maintain) into **Bootstrap** using `react-bootstrap`.

I have the given button on my original website:

[image]

I would like to reproduce it with the `react-bootstrap` library. However, I am kind of stuck as I don't understand one point or two.

I have the following component:

**image_button.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ImageProps } from "react-bootstrap/Image";
import { ButtonProps } from "react-bootstrap/Button";

export interface ImageButtonProps {
  hoverSrc: string;
}

export interface ImageButtonState {

}

export class ImageButton extends React.Component<ImageProps & ButtonProps & ImageButtonProps, ImageButtonState> {
  render() {
    return <Button active={this.props.active} block={this.props.block} variant={this.props.variant} size={this.props.size} type={this.props.type} href={this.props.href} disabled={this.props.disabled} target={this.props.target} className={`image-button`}>
      <Image src={this.props.src}/>
    </Button>
  }
}

export default ImageButton;
```

- The first question that comes to my mind is: Do I have at least the right approach?
- If I do, then how or what would be the best way to pass all the props to my sub-component? As you see, I use a "mapping" approach where I set all the values which might not be the best way to do it...
- Let say I want to customize it (when hover, change the background image?), how can I apply styles to my component?

> Note: My ultime goal would be to have a generic component that takes as props all the button/image props (and apply them) as well as ImageButton props that can be `:hover { src: /path/to/media.png }`

Thanks for any help around the subject :) I know the question is quite wide and not focus on a simple/precise point :)

Best,

Max

Answer (score 1):

since the addition of react hooks people have been moving into functional components instead of Objects.

an easy way to map all properties is using the spread operator so something like this

```
function ImageButton({src, ...props}) {
    return <Button {...props}>
        <Image src={src} />
    </Button>
}

export default ImageButton
```

also you can use css along side reactjs by importing the css file `import './style.css'`

Comment: Hello :) thanks for your answer! Really interesting I will have a look at it then :)

Comment: Hey :) I could look into  it but based on the code above (mine), when I try your approach, forwarding the props to "button" works, but not when forwarding to the image :/ Try this -> `<Button {...this.props}><Image {...this.props}/></Button>`. Also, taking in consideration that this work, would I be able to override the src of the image (based on a action, like "hover") like so: `<Button {...this.props}><Image {...this.props} src={this.props.hoverSrc}/></Button>`? Thanks :)

Comment: You should be able to forward props to Image.
however the next prop will overwrite the previous one.
so `<Image src="1" src="2" />` the src will only be 2, it will not be 1

Comment: I see that's what I thought :) thanks :) Well try by yourself.. You can't forward props to image, no idea why, I get webpack error:  `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #137; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=137&args[]=img for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

Comment: img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. are one of the props `children`?